# JNDI InvalidnameException for CN 'LastName, FirstName'

Tags: java, active-directory, jndi

I am writing to active directory using JNDI, it is successful for

`"CN=Yuri Gagarin,OU=Admins,DC=ead,DC=ubc,DC=ca"`; but fails for

`"CN=Gagarin, Yuri,OU=Admins,DC=ead,DC=ubc,DC=ca"`.

I need to store displayName, cn, name in the format 'lastName, FirstName'.

What do I need to do to get this going?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\` to escape the comma:

```
"CN=Gagarin\, Yuri,OU=Admins,DC=ead,DC=ubc,DC=ca"
```